# What does 'LHS' mean in a message from the ESLint plugin for Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, v-model

[A message from the official ESLint plugin for Vue.js](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/valid-v-model.md#book-rule-details) says:

> 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as
>   LHS.

An example which triggers that message is

```
<input v-model="foo() + bar()">
```

What does LHS mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

lhs is short for left hand side

Comment: Any idea why it says "left-hand side" and not something like "variable identifier"? @SteakOverflow Actually, it is an answer to my question.

Comment: @SteakOverflow it completely follows the guidelines and is a valid and good answer

Comment: Ok, I stopped by and read again. I think I rushed as I tend to see 1 liners as comments but in this case it’s fine. Apologies. Voted up.